# CakePHP slow on remote access

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, datatable, cakephp-2.3

i have a problem facing since 2 weeks ago:

I have a web application on Cake 2.3 and now I will put on production on a linux server with lampp, I have de domain with dyn to connect my server to the web.

The problem is that when i try to connect from my office to www.domain.com/system the app is responding excellent if we talk about speed,  but when I open from my house or another place it takes too long to show some data.

How can a fix this problem? i try to put on database configuration the host domain instead of localhost but it doesnt work.

Note: most of the time I use datatable from ajax data

Comment: Before you start investigating CakePHP, I would recommend to repeat the test with a static HTML page or a simple PHP script to exclude the possibility that it's a connection/network problem. In any case, the database configuration and the way PHP connects to the database should not be affected by the domain used to access the application.

Comment: indeed I test the tracking on my browser the ajax request and in content download says 5 seconds. this is impossible cause I've seen 9000 rows(id,name) on datatable and it takes ms(millisencods). I think its a network problem but I dont know what